# How can I check file permissions of a Linux file using Haskell?

Tags: haskell, filesystems, file-permissions

How can I determine whether a file has write / read / executable permissions for the owner of a file?

I've found `FileMode`
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Types.html#t:FileMode, but I can't seem to find a simple way to determine the permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `FileMode` is a type alias for [**`CMode`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/System-Posix-Types.html#t:CMode) with is a 32-bit number. The package further contains constants like `ownerReadMode`, `ownerWriteMode`, `ownerExecuteMode`; `groupReadMode`, `groupWriteMode`, `groupExecuteMode`; `otherReadMode`, `otherWriteMode` and `otherExecuteMode`.

You can use [**`intersectFileModes :: FileMode -> FileMode -> FileMode`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Files-ByteString.html#v:intersectFileModes) to determine the intersection. If the intersection with one of the constants is the same as that constant, then the file has that mode.

For example:

```
import System.Posix.Files(getFileStatus,fileMode,ownerReadMode)
import System.Posix.Files.ByteString(intersectFileModes)

main = do
    fs <- getFileStatus "foo.file"
    if intersectFileModes (fileMode fs) ownerReadMode == ownerReadMode
        then print "owner can read"
        else print "owner can not read"
```

To make it more convenient, we can define a function:

```
import System.Posix.Types(FileMode)
import System.Posix.Files.ByteString(intersectFileModes)

hasMode :: FileMode -> FileMode -> Bool
hasMode fa fb = intersectFileModes fa fb == fa
```

So then function `hasMode ownerReadMode` will check a filemode and return `True` if the filemode contains that permission, otherwise `False`.

Now we can rewrite the above program as:

```
import System.Posix.Types(FileMode)
import System.Posix.Files(getFileStatus,fileMode,ownerReadMode)
import System.Posix.Files.ByteString(intersectFileModes)

hasMode :: FileMode -> FileMode -> Bool
hasMode fa fb = intersectFileModes fa fb == fa

main = do
    fs <- getFileStatus "../README.md"
    if hasMode ownerReadMode (fileMode fs)
        then print "owner can read"
        else print "owner can not read"
```